# c# Nested vs Flat If Else checking for words in positions

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, optimization

I have some c# code that takes a string question and converts each word to a list so I can check for certain words in certain positions to trigger different methods. I have it written into a large If Else statement and am wondering if a nested if else would be faster because it could narrow the conditions to check by the first word. See example below. Or would a flat If Else be faster? Is there a faster way to check for certain words in certain positions using substrings?

Nested if else

```
string question = "How long is the Mississippi River"
List<string> questionSplit = question.Split(' ').ToList();   

if (questionSplit[0] == "How")
{
    if (questionSplit[1] == "long")
    {
        MeasureLength();
    }
    else if (questionSplit[1] == "high")
    {
        GetElevation();
    }
}
else if (questionSplit[0] == "What")
{
    DoSomething();
}

else if (questionSplit[0] == "When")
{
    DoSomething();
}
else if (questionSplit[0] == "Where")
{
     DoSomething();
}
```

VS flat If Else

```
if (questionSplit[0] == "How" && questionSplit[1] == "long")
{
    MeasureLength();   
}
else if (questionSplit[0] == "How" && questionSplit[1] == "high")
{
    GetElevation();   
}
else if (questionSplit[0] == "What")
{
    DoSomething();
}

else if (questionSplit[0] == "When")
{
    DoSomething();
}
else if (questionSplit[0] == "Where")
{
     DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: The nested one would be faster since it's not evaluating the same condition more than once (in the case of `"How high"`). If the strings are input from the user, you might consider doing a case-insensitive comparison, however.

Comment: While technically I believe @RufusL is correct, I think you would have a hard time actually measuring a difference in speed between the two.

Comment: Put a Stopwatch.Start() at the beginning of both if statements and a StopWatch.Stop() at the end and Console.WriteLine(EllapsedMilliseconds). This will show you which one is faster. Look up StopWatch if you haven't tried it before, it's really cool stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea to consider that should be faster is using a `Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>>` to store the keywords along with the method that's used to evaluate the rest of the string. This is assuming that your methods take in a string (user input) and return a string (result to display to user).

Note that there are surely much better ways to process user input, but this is one step in simplifying the code you have above.

First, we have the methods you're calling to do evaluations, all of which must take a string and return a string for this example:

```
public static string MeasureLength(string input)
{
    return $"MeasureLength called with: '{input}'";
}

public static string GetElevation(string input)
{
    return $"GetElevation called with: '{input}'";
}

public static string DoSomething(string input)
{
    return $"DoSomething called with: '{input}'";
}
```

Then we have a dictionary that maps "keywords" to methods (note that I've compounded the keywords for the `"How"` cases into `"how long"` and `"how much"`):

```
private static Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>> KeyWordMethodMap =
    new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        {"how long", MeasureLength},
        {"how high", GetElevation},
        {"what", DoSomething},
        {"when", DoSomething},
        {"where", DoSomething},
    };
```

So now that we have our mappings, all we have to do is parse the "keyword" from the beginning of the string, try to get the matching method from our dictionary, and then invoke that method if it was found (note that this is simplified code, and some validation should be done that we're not accessing invalid indexes):

```
private static void Main()
{
    var question = "How long is the Mississippi River";
    var questionSplit = question.Split(' ').ToList();
    var key = questionSplit[0];

    // Add the second word if the first one is 'how'
    if (key.Equals("how", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        key += $" {questionSplit[1]}";
    }

    // This will hold the method we need to call if the key is found
    Func<string, string> methodToInvoke;

    // Try to get the method for this key in our dictionary and then invoke it if found
    if (KeyWordMethodMap.TryGetValue(key, out methodToInvoke))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(methodToInvoke.Invoke(question));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, I don't understand the command: {key}");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

Output in Console window is: `MeasureLength called with: 'How long is the Mississippi River'`

Comment: Thanks Rufus. I tested the Dictionary out and it seems to be working faster but i haven't finished it and added stopwatch yet. Since the Dictionary requires string input and string output (though most of my methods are void output) i am having trouble with the async methods that return Task<string>. Can you use a mix of return types in a Dictionary like string and Task<string>. Or can I wrap the async methods in another method to call the Task then return the result as string not Task<string>? Thanks @Rufus L

Comment: No, the keys are all the same type as each other and the values are all the same type as each other. You could wrap your methods so their signatures match or declare the value type as a common interface or class between all the values.